# How do I use CC and BCC in UNIX mail?

Tags: shell, email, unix

I have the function below which uses the mail.
How do I add cc or bcc in it?
Doing this do not work: cat << EOF | mail ${CONTACT_EMAIL} -b email@email.com.br...

```
function SendMail () {
        # Getting e-mails body text
        TEXT=$(cat ${LOG_DIR}/${PROCESS_ID}.log)

cat << EOF | mail ${CONTACT_EMAIL}
From: ${MAIL_FROM}
Subject: X
To: X}
Cc: Leandro.Takeda@teste.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"
---q1w2e3r4t5
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

X

EOF

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`man mail` on my comp suggests `-b a,b,c` should go before to-address(es).

```
mail -b email@email.com.br ${CONTACT_EMAIL}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sendmail` program directly without `mail` program help.

```
SENDMAIL=/usr/sbin/sendmail

${SENDMAIL} -i -- ${CONTACT_EMAIL} Leandro.Takeda@teste.com jd@example.net <<EOF
From: ${MAIL_FROM}
Subject: X
To: ${CONTACT_EMAIL}
Cc: Leandro.Takeda@teste.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"

---q1w2e3r4t5
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

X

EOF
```